# How to launch app from the web/cloud

Tags: google-app-engine, amazon-web-services, cloud, twilio, google-cloud-sql

I have developed an app in Twilio which I would like to run from the cloud. I tried learning about AWS and Google App Engine but am quite confused at this stage:

I have 2 questions which I hope to get your help on:

1) How can I store my scripts and database in the cloud? Right now, everything is running out of my local machine but I would like to transfer the scripts and db to another server and run my app at a predetermined time of day. What would be the best way to do this?

2) How can I write a batch file to run my app at a predetermined time of day in the cloud?

I understand this does not have code, but I really hope someone can point me to the right direction. I have spent lots of time trying to understand this myself but still am unsure. Tks in adv.

Update: The application is a Twilio app that makes calls to people, the script simply applies an algorithm to make calls in a certain fashion and the database is a mysql db that provides the details of people to be called.

Comment: In what language did you write your app? In which container does it run?

Answer (score 1):

This is quite difficult to provide an exact answer without understanding what is the application, what is the DB or what is the script that you wish to run.

I can give you a couple of ideas that might be helpful in such cases.

OpsWorks (http://aws.amazon.com/opsworks/) is a managed service for managing applications. You can define your stack (multiple layers like web, workers, DB...) and what are the chef recipes that should run in various points in the life of the instances in each layer (startup, shutdown, app deployment or stack modification..). Then you can use the ability to add instances to each layer in specific days and hours, to implement the functionality of running at predetermined times as you requested.

In such a solution you can either have some of your instances (like DB) always on, or even to bootstrap them using the chef recipes every day, with restore from snapshot on start and create snapshot on shutdown.

Another AWS service that you use is Data Pipeline (http://aws.amazon.com/datapipeline/). It is designed to move data periodically between data sources, for example from a MySQL database to Amazon Redshift, the Data warehouse service. But you can use it to trigger scripts and run random shell scripts that you wish (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/datapipeline/latest/DeveloperGuide/dp-object-shellcommandactivity.html), and schedule it to run in various conditions like every hour/day or specific times (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/datapipeline/latest/DeveloperGuide/dp-concepts-schedules.html).

Comment: Thanks Guy. I am checking these out. It seems like it will take a lot of work on AWS/Google App Engine (or would it?). Seems like Heroku may be able to do things faster (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9802259/why-do-people-use-heroku-when-aws-is-present-whats-distinguishing-about-heroku). However, I am not too familiar with it.

Comment: btw, I have updated my question with more details in case you're relooking it

Answer (score 1):

A simple path here would be just to create an EC2 instance in AWS, and put the components needed to run your app there. A thorough walk through is here:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/get-set-up-for-amazon-ec2.html

Essentially you will create an EC2 virtual machine, which you can for most purposes treat just like any other Linux server. You can install MySQL on it, copy your script there, and run it. Of course whatever container or support libraries your code requires will need to be installed as well.

You don't say what OS you are using locally, but if it is Mac or Linux, you should be able to follow almost the same process to get your script running on an EC2 instance that you used on your local machine.

As you get to know AWS, there are sophisticated services you can use for deployment, infrastructure orchestration, database services, and so on. But just to get started running a script from a virtual machine should be pretty straightforward.

Answer (score 1):

I recently developed a Twilio application using Ruby on Rails for the backend and found [Heroku](http://heroku.com) extremely simple to setup and launch. While Heroku does cost more than AWS, I found that the time I saved using Heroku more than made up this. As an early stage startup, we wanted to spend our time developing important features, and not "wasting" time optimizing our AWS cloud.

However, while I believe Heroku is ideal for early-stage websites/startups I do believe hosting should be reevaluated once a company reaches a certain size. At some point it becomes economically viable to devote resources into optimizing an AWS cloud solution because it will be cheaper than Heroku in the long run.